# how to show all data points on y axis in ggplot heatmaps?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-text, ggplotly

I've created a heatmap using ggplot

```
library(plyr)
library(scales)
guide_ind <- ddply(guide_tag[company == FALSE], .(tag), transform, rescale = rescale(count))


(p <- ggplotly(ggplot(guide_ind, aes(tag, username)) + 
                 geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale),colour = "white") + 
                 scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle= 90, hjust=1), legend.position= "bottom")   )
  )
```

I have about 700 rows of user name, and I would like to make sure that all the usernames are visible in document so that when I produce this in markdown, it will show the names individually instead of overlapping like the picture below.

[image]

I've tried using the fig.height, and gplot heatmap, but neither has worked.

Does anyone have suggestions to how to make all data points visible on the yaxis?

Comment: we can't test you code since we don't have access to **guide_tag**. But why not change the size of your axis.x label?